# ggplot extra bar in barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is

```
> data
    width          variable value
1     200   mappedEnsemblTx   110
2     400   mappedEnsemblTx   392
3     600   mappedEnsemblTx  1055
4     800   mappedEnsemblTx  2615
5    1000   mappedEnsemblTx  5201
101   200 UnmappedEnsemblTx  3927
102   400 UnmappedEnsemblTx  5175
103   600 UnmappedEnsemblTx  3220
104   800 UnmappedEnsemblTx  4856
105  1000 UnmappedEnsemblTx  7130
```

When I plot this, instead of two bars I can see three or probably four bars in my plot. 
Minimal code is as below:

```
 library(ggplot2)


g = ggplot(dat.melt,aes(x=factor(width),y=value,fill=variable), format(scientific=FALSE)) 
g = g + geom_bar(stat='identity',position='dodge') 
g <- g + theme_bw()
g = g + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-90, hjust=0, size = 16), axis.text.y=theme_text(size=16))
g <- g + opts(axis.title.x = theme_text(size=18), axis.title.y = theme_text(size=18, angle=90) )
g = g + scale_x_discrete('Total widths of the Ensembl Transcripts') + scale_y_continuous(name = 'Count') 
g = g + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,7000))
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `dat.melt` meant to be `data.melt`? If not, is it an error that `data` doesn't appear anywhere in your minimal code?

Comment: I'm infinitely ignorant of both R and ggplot, but why would you expect only two bars? You've put `width` on the x-axis and there are five different values of `width`. Shouldn't you be getting five bars? (Or indeed ten, two at each x-position, moved aside from one another by `position='dodge'`?) Can you be more specific about what you expected to see (surely you can say more than "two bars") and what you actually saw (surely you can say more than "three or probably four bars")?

Comment: I am sorry for mistake. data.melt needs to be data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
data.melt <- structure(list(width = c(200L, 400L, 600L, 800L, 1000L, 200L, 
400L, 600L, 800L, 1000L), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("mappedEnsemblTx", "UnmappedEnsemblTx"
), class = "factor"), value = c(110L, 392L, 1055L, 2615L, 5201L, 
3927L, 5175L, 3220L, 4856L, 7130L)), .Names = c("width", "variable", 
"value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105"))
```

and your example

```
g <- ggplot(data.melt,aes(x=factor(width),y=value,fill=variable),
            format(scientific=FALSE)) 
g <- g + geom_bar(stat='identity',position='dodge') 
g <- g + theme_bw()
g <- g + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-90, hjust=0, size = 16), 
              axis.text.y=theme_text(size=16))
g <- g + opts(axis.title.x = theme_text(size=18),
              axis.title.y = theme_text(size=18, angle=90) )
g <- g + scale_x_discrete('Total widths of the Ensembl Transcripts') +
         scale_y_continuous(name = 'Count') 
g <- g + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,7000))
g
```

I get:

[image: barplot example]

which is what I would expect; 5 groups of 2 bars. 5 groups because you have 5 values of `width` and 2 levels in the factor `variable`.

That is with:

```
R> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 Patched (2012-04-16 r59049)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.utf8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.utf8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                LC_NAME=C                
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       grid_2.15.0       
 [5] MASS_7.3-17        memoise_0.1        munsell_0.3        plyr_1.7.1        
 [9] proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.1     scales_0.2.0      
[13] stringr_0.6        tools_2.15.0
```

Comment: Thanks galvin, there was a problem in my input data.